# Using Regular Expression to Find content between two double quotes

Tags: ubuntu, sed

I am trying to use a regular expression to find and replace the contents that are enclosed by two double quotes in a xml file using `sed`, e.g., `"contents like this..."`.

In particular, I would like to replace whatever the content of `autoLogoffTime` is with a fixed string `"2:15,AM"` in the xml file.

**Some contents of my XML file**

```
<SystemSettings executionSummaryExportDir="/home/Jts/" autoLogoffTime="11:45,PM" repetitiveSnapshotDelay="500" snapshotCostReminderLimit="10" snapshotExcessiveUsageLimit="50" autoExportDirectory="/home/$
```

There are a few of these XML files in different directories that I would like to replace the string. The content of `autoLogoffTime` can be with or without a space in it, e.g.:

```
autoLogoffTime="11:45,PM" 
autoLogoffTime="11:45, PM"
```

I tried to find all the characters (white space and non-whitespace) by using `*` but it does not seem the right regular expression.

```
sed -i.bak 's/autoLogoffTime="*"/autoLogoffTime="2:15,AM"/g' file.xml
```

could someone kindly help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the best way to modify an XML file is to use XML-specific tools.  `sed` should be used only if those tools are not available.  So, use this answer only if there is a good reason why they can't be installed on your system.

In a shell glob, `"*"` means two double-quotes with any characters between them.
`sed`, however, doesn't use globs, it uses regular expressions.  In a regular expression, `*` means zero-or-more of the previous character.  Thus, `"*"` matches zero-or-more `"` followed by `"`.

Try:

```
sed -i.bak 's/autoLogoffTime="[^"]*"/autoLogoffTime="2:15,AM"/g' file.xml
```

`"[^"]*"` matches `"`, followed by zero-or-more of any character *except* `"`, followed by `"`.

Comment: Thank you, John for the answer. What would you recommend using for XML string replacement? Do you mind providing an answer using a XML-specific tool? Would really appreciate it.

Comment: `xmlstarlet` seems to be popular.  There may be others.  (I've had little reason to use one myself.)